# Visual Studio 2017 Extension for custom C# refactoring across entire solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, refactoring, visual-studio-extensions

I would like to develop a *Visual Studio **2017*** Extension to apply some custom refactoring and code cleanup to an entire C# legacy solution.

The kind of refactoring I would like to apply is not supported via Visual Studio or other refactoring extensions I have looked at (like ReSharper, etc.). I believe, I can figure out the refactoring logic itself.

I am however lost how to start. I have seen a number of articles that illustrate how to get started with a C# refactoring project *in Visual Studio **2015***. 
Things seem to be quite different in Visual Studio 2017, though. There is just a "VISX Project" template to start with, not specifically a refactoring template. Documentation and VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples state that you can add "Language service and editor extension points" and "Add refactoring or language analyzers to fix and improve code", but I have not actually seen any steps how to get there.

What are the next steps to create a custom refactoring which I can run against my solution? Note that I do not want to add a hint to the editor, which I can select on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have **.NET Compiler Platform SDK** installed:

[image]

With it you will have the **Code Refactoring** project template:

[image]

Comment: Ah - that's it! Adding that gives me the Code Refactoring project type as well as the Refactoring item when adding to a VISX project.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Roslyn examples](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Samples-and-Walkthroughs), with which you will perform the actual refactoring. Probably the "ImplementNotifyPropertyChanged" example will be a good starting point for you.

For the non-refactoring VSIX-part use any ordinary tutorial on writing Visual Studio extensions.

BTW: Your question is a bit broad for this page.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the Roslyn examples. I am still having issues closing the gap between my empty VISX Project and the next step. The documentation seems to suggest I should do "Add Item" and then select from the "Extensions", but there is nothing in there that looks like a refactoring to me. The Roslyn Examples show the refactoring part, but I am not sure what to do with these as they cannot be run as a Visual Studio plugin - or I am missing something again...

Comment: Double-checked back and forth:  [this tutorial](https://michaelscodingspot.com/visual-studio-2017-extension-development-tutorial-part-3-add-context-menu-get-selected-code/) has a screenshot where it offers to add a refactoring. My Visual Studio has Add Command, etc. but not the Analyzer, Code Fix and Refactoring...

Comment: Was interested in this; built the example and tried it, but the example itself doesn't wokr for me :-/